# Floating number issue

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

All,

I have a floating number issue that I need help with. I just started with Objective-C and this seems to be a pretty simple solution, but I'm at a loss after my search. In short, I'm adding the numerical input from four TextFields together and displaying the answer in a UILabel. My answer is in the correct decimal format, but only displays 0.00 and not the correct sum. Im sure it it something to do with converting between string and float, but I need some assistance:

```
- (IBAction)Calc1:(id)sender {

    int result = [oranges.text doubleValue] + 
                    [bananas.text doubleValue] +
                        [grapes.text doubleValue] +
                            [pears.text doubleValue];

    text123.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.1f", result];

}
```

Comment: what is the value of each of the texts?

Comment: @user890803 You need to post more code.  You can not expect to to store a double in an int value and not loss precision.  result needs to be a double, post more code to see why it messes up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want to declare result as a double...

```
double result = ....
```

Comment: Have you posted your entire method body? I cannot understand how you get a NaN simply by adding numbers?

Comment: You get NaN when one of the original numbers is NaN. That is, when one of the text strings does not represent a number.

Comment: In my tests I just get 0 if the text does not represent a number.

Answer (score 0):

You use `int` type to store `double` type, then accuracy is lost.

You should set the result variable to the `double` type.

Comment: When I set result as a double I get nan in the UIlable

Comment: @user890803 NaN means that "not a number", you should check your code.